# Given an arc length and a radius, how do I find the endpoint

Tags: geometry

Trying to do some game programing, and I need to figure out how to position some objects evenly in a circle.

I made a graphic to illustrate my point because I don't know if I'm asking it correctly

[image]

Comment: Are you going around a circle about the origin?

Comment: @Pinwheeler Also, what do you mean by evenly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is about a circle centred on the origin, after travelling an angle of $\theta$, your co-ordinates would be $r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$. When arclength is $a$, the relation $a=r\theta$ can be used to give $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $r$:

$$(x,y)=\left(r\cos\left(\frac ar\right),r\sin\left(\frac ar\right)\right)$$

If the centre is somewhere different with centre $(c,d)$, then just use the transformation $x\mapsto x+c, y\mapsto y+d$, giving 
$$(x,y)=\left(r\cos\left(\frac ar\right)+c,r\sin\left(\frac ar\right)+d\right)$$